# How to avoid having static resource request get's routed to interceptors?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm using the latest Spring (4.1.1) with tomcat 7.0.52 . I have enabled annotation driven mvc.

In my application, I defined an interceptor:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="com.abc.UserAgentChangeInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Alongside, I defined resources:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**/*" location="/desktop"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/**/*.css" location="/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/**/*.js" location="/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/**/*.gif" location="/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/**/*.htm" location="/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/**/*.svg" location="/"/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/**/*.png" location="/"/>
```

However, when request come in, even for static resources/assets, they still get routed to interceptors first.

I am aware of the following practice that can solve the problem:

1. use `mvc:exclude-mapping` inside `mvc:interceptor` to exclude the requests made on the above url being routed to my interceptor, but it seems to violate the DRY principle, and I really don't like the look and feel.
2. use `mvc:mapping` on interceptors. However, I am using annotation driven `@RequestMapping` on so many handlers and there are so many different path. That solution also doesn't work cleanly for me.

I also came across opinions saying using `@ControllerAdvice` instead of interceptors can help alleviate the issue, but based on what I've learned by reading Spring documentation, `@ControllerAdvice` doesn't have any method similar to `preHandle()` that executes before `@Controller`s

I still prefer to solve this problem using the Spring XML configuration approach rather than defining a `@Configuration` class in my application. Just a convention thing.

Any opinion is deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current "solution" that I found is to use aspect. For example, if I want to intercept only request to `@RequestMapping` method in `@Controller`. I would do

```
@Aspect
@Order(1)
@Component
public class UserAgentChangeAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..)) && @within(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller) && @annotation(org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping)")
    private void pointcut() {
    }

    @Before("pointcut()")
    public void preHandle()
            throws Exception {
        // logic
        }
    }

    @After("pointcut()")
    public void postHandle()
            throws Exception {
        // logic
    }
}
```

I will mark this one as Accepted. If anyone has better idea please post it and I'll accept it if I see fit.

Answer (score 0):

Approach-1: Use mapping path in interceptor configuration

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
      <mvc:mapping path="/path" />
          <bean
             class="bean" />
     </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

Approach-2: along with mvc:resources, specify

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: I am using annotation driven `@RequestMapping` on handlers and there're so many path. Thus, I didn't use path mapping in interceptors. Thanks for the help.